# FlipFromRight UIView animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

First here's my code:

```
[_helperView addSubview:_navigationController.view];
[_helperView addSubview:itemView];

[UIView beginAnimations:@"pageFlipAnimation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:_helperView cache:NO];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(pageFlipAnimationDidStop)];
[itemView removeFromSuperview];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

My problem with this that nothing is animated. If I add the _navigationController.view and itemView before (I mean not in this method) everything is ok, but when I add before the animation it does nothing. I also tried to call again the animation in the animation didStopSelector and also works there.
Can you help me please why it doesn't want to work in this case? Any suggestions how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably give the UI the chance to effectuate the addition of `itemView`. To do this, add a line after `addSubview:itemView`:

```
[self performSelector(removeAnim:) withObject:itemView afterDelay:0.01];
```

and move the animation block to a function

```
-(void)removeAnim:(UIVieW*)itemView
```

This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use **QuartzCore.framework** With these animations.

```
-(void)viewSlideInFromRightToLeft:(UIView *)views
{
    CATransition *transition = nil;
    transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.5;//kAnimationDuration
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromRight;
    transition.delegate = self;
    [views.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
}

-(void)viewSlideInFromLeftToRight:(UIView *)views
{
    CATransition *transition = nil;
    transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.5;//kAnimationDuration
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromLeft;
    transition.delegate = self;
    [views.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
}

-(void)viewSlideInFromTopToBottom:(UIView *)views
{
    CATransition *transition = nil;
    transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.5;//kAnimationDuration
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromBottom ;
    transition.delegate = self;
    [views.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
}

-(void)viewSlideInFromBottomToTop:(UIView *)views
{
    CATransition *transition = nil;
    transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.5;//kAnimationDuration
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromTop ;
    transition.delegate = self;
    [views.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
}
```

For *AnimationType* you can use following option:-> `kCATransitionMoveIn`, `kCATransitionPush`, `kCATransitionReveal`, `kCATransitionFade`

For *AnimationSubType* you can use following option:-> `kCATransitionFromLeft`, `kCATransitionFromRight`, `kCATransitionFromTop`, `kCATransitionFromBottom`